# Junit 4 cucumber reporter skip test

Tags: junit4, cucumber-junit

I'm writing a cucumber gherkin.formatter reporter and formatter and I'm looking to be able to skip junit cucumber tests from within the class.

With TestNG I can use the throw new SkipException() however I can't see a way to skip tests with junit.

I'm looking to skip individual tests scenarios from inside the startOfScenarioLifeCycle function depending on conditions determined at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Throw a `org.junit.AssumptionViolatedException` exception to skip in junit

Comment: This seems to skip the whole Feature, not just the scenario, is there any way to just skip a single scenario?